# Optimizing performance for processing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, cython, large-data

I've got a dataframe with two columns: Time (string) and Tweet (also string).

I've written some code to clean up the tweet for some machine learning applications and I would like to apply the cleaning function to the entire Tweet column.

My problem is, the data is fairly large, around 8,500,000 rows of data.

```
    Time                                        Tweet
0   """Tue Apr 07 10:40:33 +0000 2015"""    " ""@caiittlliinnx @RoscoStraughan man flu is the worst though so I have to back Ross up here like"""
1   """Tue Apr 07 10:40:35 +0000 2015"""    " ""RT @CTVLondon: Two farms near Woodstock have been placed under quarantined after avian influenza was found at a turkey farm."""
2   """Tue Apr 07 10:40:38 +0000 2015"""    " ""@DREWXAVECAO @EXFLOP Flu fez as pazes com Fla, mas coleciona desafetos dentro e fora do futebol (07\/04\/15-06h00):"""
3   """Tue Apr 07 10:40:42 +0000 2015"""    " ""3-0 hahahahaha going up mmr ;)"""
4   """Tue Apr 07 10:40:42 +0000 2015"""    " ""Flu itu sesuatu :\/"""
```

I've tried 3 approaches:

1. Looping - I've tried doing a simple loop and applying the cleaning functions to each element in the df.Tweet series.  That works but takes forever.

   ```
   df.cleaned = np.zeros_like(df.Tweet)
   for i in range(len(df)):
       df.cleaned[i] = clean_tweet( df.Tweet[i])
   ```
2. I tried the `df.apply` method, but that also takes a long time, and even worse, I have no way to monitor how much data I have cleaned.
3. I tried parallelizing the code using `Pool`

   ```
   pool = Pool(4)

   chunksize = 1000000

   reader = pd.read_csv('filename',chunksize = chunksize)

   flist = []

   for i in reader:
       f = apply_async(clean_tweet,[i])
       flist.apply(f)

   alist = [j.get() for j in flist]

   df = pd.concat(alist)
   ```

I'm not sure how well that works either.  I can't let my script run for days, so I am looking for something that could run overnight at the latest.

Can someone recommend an approach?  Maybe cythonizing the script?  I'm open to suggestions.

Here is the code for `clean_tweet'

```
def clean_tweet(x):

    cleaning = BeautifulSoup(x,"lxml")

    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", cleaning.get_text())

    words = letters_only.lower().split()

    words = [w for w in words if not w in (stopwords.words("english")+[u'rt'])]

    almost = " ".join(words)

    return re.sub(r'\b\w{1}\b', '', almost)
```

Comment: What is the code of `clean_tweet`? The overhead might be there.

Comment: @DeepSpace You may be right.  See the edit

Comment: I would start by using `str` methods instead of both 2 `re.sub`, or at least the first one. `re.sub` is a resource hog compared to `str.replace`.

Comment: How about some profiling first?

Comment: I doubt you are going to be able to achieve huge speedups here, the clean_tweet function has to be run individually on each tweet. Speedups in pandas generally come from making use of vectorization, which won't help here. Maybe compile your regexes outside the `clean_tweet` function to make sure they're not being recompiled on each run.

Comment: Could also create a set to store `stopwords.words("english") + [u'rt']` (for faster `in` lookups) and define it outside `clean_tweet` to make sure the append operation isn't being run each time.

Comment: @Mike good idea. I haven't found a way to run the Timor profiler in my IDE (canopy). Still looking to do that.

Comment: Use `cProfile`. Comes with the standard lib.